# How to rotate sprite continuously at a defined speed? And general questions about game programming

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an image which is rendered:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(new Sprite(new Texture("img1.png"), 64, 64), x, y);
    batch.end()
```

where x and y are used to center the sprite in the middle of the screen depending upon the screen's resolution.

1. I know I can use [`rotate(float degrees)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) to rotate it, but how do I do so continuously? I think I need to use delta time in some way, for example, `x += 50 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();` but this does not rotate it continuously. The image is displayed for one frame before jumping elsewhere for one frame (seems like it's translating frame by frame instead).
2. If I want the (one) sprite to have multiple collision detections (for example, each colored arc [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUSqE.png) reacts differently, can overlaying an invisible circle on top that moves along with the arc and using math on that circle solve this problem? Instead of having a separate sprite for each colored arc. Is there an easier way to do this?
3. For a game, is it okay to not use layouts/XML for designing levels (i.e. hard coding everything instead)? Will this make it more difficult to make apps compatible for multiple screen resolutions?

I'm new to this so I hope these questions make sense.

Comment: there is no any method of Batch  batch.draw(sprite, x, y); where sprite is object of Sprite class. Is your sprite is object of Texture or TextureRegion ?

Comment: It's an object of Texture.

Comment: I edited the post, should be clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotate your sprite forever in this way

```
public class TestGame extends Game {

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Sprite ball;
    Texture ballTex;
    private int spriteRotationSpeed=1;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
        ballTex=new Texture("image/bone.png");
        ball=new Sprite(ballTex);
        ball.setSize(50,50);
        ball.setOrigin(25,25);
        ball.setPosition(0,0);


    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        ball.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.end();
        rotateSprite();
    }

    private void rotateSprite(){

        float rotation=ball.getRotation();
        rotation+=spriteRotationSpeed;
        if(rotation>360)
            rotation-=360;
        ball.setRotation(rotation);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        ballTex.dispose();
        spriteBatch.dispose();
    }
}
```